Novel about a time-travel war heralded by a ring of gamma-ray bursts
This was a science fiction full-length novel that I read sometime in the last 10 years--and I think was published not long before--yet most of the details have escaped me (I think perhaps it wasn't very good? XD). The details I can remember are as follows:

The arrival in the future of The Evil is presaged in the modern-day by the shockingly impossible observation of a perfect ring of six(?) gamma-ray bursts, located across the universe from Earth.  The Evil's essence is apparently riding the beam produced by this colossal explosion to reach our galaxy.
Some agent of The Evil is present on modern-day Earth, and acts through various means to destroy all recorded evidence of the GRB event to stymie any efforts to plan for or resist the arrival of The Evil. Society ends up believing the entire thing was some kind of hoax.
A single copy of the evidence gets overlooked and eventually found by some of the protagonists (naturally) and contains some kind of information that is key to their success in the temporal war.
Most of the rest of the story follows certain individuals in various time periods, both in the deep past and in the future; these people are key "warriors" who will be essential to fighting The Evil on its arrival in the distant future.  Their stories all include encounters with agents of The Evil who try to corrupt or influence them away from the protagonists' side of things, or otherwise taking actions to sabotage the resistance.
These key characters I don't think were taken out of their time to the future, but instead died naturally and were resurrected at the appropriate time in the future.
-One of these key characters was Loki, who was initially one of the corrupted agents of The Evil in the past, but then makes a heel-face turn and joins the protagonists.  In the time of the final battle, he reverses course and rejoins the Evil... but the protagonists knew he was fated to do this, as was his nature as a trickster archetype.

"The Evil" is just what I'm calling the villain of the piece, since I can't remember what it was actually called. XD

Hm. I might've read something similar in the 90s. Was there a scene where agents of this "Evil" sabotage an experimental nuclear fusion reactor somewhere near the beginning of the novel?

I don't think so?  But my memory of the story is vague enough that I can't wholly discount it either. XD
